# JQ filtering on fields in nested Objects

Tags: arrays, json, bash, filtering, jq

I have a large set of data, I am using JQ to construct the object that contains only the data I am interested in for a record. My problem is that I am starting to see duplicate objects, it seems my syntax is incorrect.

I am working with an object that contains flat fields and an array of subObjects, there are particular fields I want to pull out and make new objects that have all the data I want. Including some flat fields and some fields from the array objects.

Here is a smaller sample that helps demonstrate problem `tmpData.json`

```
{
"id": "0001",
"type": "donut",
"name": "Cake",
"ppu": 0.55,
"batter": [{
        "id": "1001",
        "type": "Regular"
    },
    {
        "id": "1002",
        "type": "Chocolate"
    },
    {
        "id": "1003",
        "type": "Blueberry"
    },
    {
        "id": "1004",
        "type": "Devil's Food"
    }
]
}
```

I run this : `cat tmpData.txt | jq {'id: .id, type: .type, batter: .batter[].id'}`

Which outputs this non-json set of objects (it's missing commas)

```
{
  "id": "0001",
  "type": "donut",
  "batter": "1001"
}
{
  "id": "0001",
  "type": "donut",
  "batter": "1002"
}
{
  "id": "0001",
  "type": "donut",
  "batter": "1003"
}
{
  "id": "0001",
  "type": "donut",
  "batter": "1004"
}
```

This is good. I now have objects each containing the parentID `0001` and the different items in the array are associated in each object.

When I run: `cat tmpData.txt | jq {'id: .id, type: .type, batterID: .batter[].id, batterType: .batter[].type'}`

With the added `type` field I get a lot of duplicates that wrongly associate items

```
{
  "id": "0001",
  "type": "donut",
  "batterID": "1001",
  "batterType": "Regular"
}
{
  "id": "0001",
  "type": "donut",
  "batterID": "1001",
  "batterType": "Chocolate"
}
{
  "id": "0001",
  "type": "donut",
  "batterID": "1001",
  "batterType": "Blueberry"
}
{
  "id": "0001",
  "type": "donut",
  "batterID": "1001",
  "batterType": "Devil's Food"
}
{
  "id": "0001",
  "type": "donut",
  "batterID": "1002",
  "batterType": "Regular"
}
{
  "id": "0001",
  "type": "donut",
  "batterID": "1002",
  "batterType": "Chocolate"
}
{
  "id": "0001",
  "type": "donut",
  "batterID": "1002",
  "batterType": "Blueberry"
}
{
  "id": "0001",
  "type": "donut",
  "batterID": "1002",
  "batterType": "Devil's Food"
}
{
  "id": "0001",
  "type": "donut",
  "batterID": "1003",
  "batterType": "Regular"
}
{
  "id": "0001",
  "type": "donut",
  "batterID": "1003",
  "batterType": "Chocolate"
}
{
  "id": "0001",
  "type": "donut",
  "batterID": "1003",
  "batterType": "Blueberry"
}
{
  "id": "0001",
  "type": "donut",
  "batterID": "1003",
  "batterType": "Devil's Food"
}
{
  "id": "0001",
  "type": "donut",
  "batterID": "1004",
  "batterType": "Regular"
}
{
  "id": "0001",
  "type": "donut",
  "batterID": "1004",
  "batterType": "Chocolate"
}
{
  "id": "0001",
  "type": "donut",
  "batterID": "1004",
  "batterType": "Blueberry"
}
{
  "id": "0001",
  "type": "donut",
  "batterID": "1004",
  "batterType": "Devil's Food"
}
```

Now I see that each `batterID` is in an object with every type `regular, chocolate, blueberry`. But in fact `1002` is only ever `chocolate`.

My ideal output would be like this

```
 [{
"id": "0001",
"type": "donut",
"batterID": "1001",
"batterType": "Regular"
},
{
"id": "0001",
"type": "donut",
"batterID": "1002",
"batterType": "Chocolate"
}]
```

Your expertise is appreciated!

EDIT SOLVED: working command: `cat tmpData.txt | jq '[{id, type} + (.batter[] | {batterId: .id, batterType: .type})]'`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. The output "without commas" is a stream of JSON; to emit an array, wrap your jq filter in square brackets.
2. You can abbreviate `{id: id, type: .type}` to `{id, type}`
3. Your filter which repeats .batter[] has the effect of creating a Cartesian product.  What you evidently want
   instead is to expand .batter just once.

Putting everything together:

```
[{id, type} + (.batter[] | {batterId: .id, batterType: .type})]
```

Comment: I am getting the error
```-bash: syntax error near unexpected token `(' ``` Could you show how this looks with the JQ command? @peak

Comment: Try putting the jq program in a file, say program.jq, and invoking jq with the -f option, e.g. `jq -f program.jq tmpData.json`

Comment: Turns out it was just that I needed to enclose the whole JQ command in single quotes.. See edit.. Thank you!!